# filtering complex collections by keywords

Tags: azure-cognitive-search

Is any way to filter a complex collection by keyword? We have a complex entity named Phase, and Phase has a property named EntityTitle, we want to filter out all the Phase whose title contains the keyword "Completed". I tried both contains and search.ismatch, but none of them support. Appreciate any idea. Thanks.

"Filter":"(Phases/any(phase: contains(phase/EntityTitle, 'Completed')))"

"Filter":"(Phases/any(phase: search.ismatch('Completed', 'phase/EntityTitle')))"

Answer (score 1):

Indeed "search.ismatch" and "contains" are not supported inside lambda expressions when filtering complex types, you should instead use "eq". See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-query-troubleshoot-collection-filters#cheat-sheet-for-collection-filter-rules

An example for your scenario would be

```
Phases/any(phase: phase/EntityTitle eq 'Completed')
```